# Load all cell content asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

There are plenty questions about how to load images and other downloaded data asynchronously, but there are no questions about asynchronously loading those images (once they are downloaded) into the UI.

I am trying to achieve 60 fps scrolling on my UICollectionView although I am looking for a solution that works for all views.

For example, if I have images in my Assets folder that I want to load into a quickly scrolling UIScrollView, it takes time for them to be brought into memory and then drawn in the UI. Is there some way to cache these images in memory first (while not hurting memory/using too much) and then load them into the cells once they are cached in memory?

As I understand it now, when I say,

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "grapes")
```

the assets folder `grapes` is opened and read from, and then it brings the corresponding image (1x, 2x, or 3x) into memory. After the correct image is brought into memory, `cell.imageView.image` is assigned to it and then the image is drawn. Is this accurate? Does all of this happen on the main thread? If so, then doesn't this have the potential to clog up the main thread and cause the device to skip some frames?

I assume that a similar process occurs when solving complex expressions, for example, or formatting text. If so, then can and how do I create the content to be loaded asynchronously so that the main thread will not get clogged (even at the expense of temporarily empty content views)?

Comment: @Rob, by "image isn't appropriately sized for the UI", do you mean that the UIImageView needs to perform more operations for scaling or something else?

Comment: I was talking about an image view that is, say 40x40 points, but you're using an image that is 1200x1200 pixels and you use a content mode of `.scaleAspectFit` or `.scaleAspectFill`. Really any situation where you're relying on `contentMode` to appropriately scale your image. Or, obviously, if you are calling your own scaling/cropping routines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can take a few milliseconds to load and image into memory. It can especially affect the experience if the image isn't appropriate sized for the UI (e.g. you're relying upon `contentMode` of something like `scaleAspectFit` or `.scaleAspectFill` to have image sized appropriately; or if you're manually resizing/cropping images yourself). That can rather innocuously result in something that is surprisingly computationally complex.

Generally, it's not enough to be problematic but it can prevent you from achieving optimal 60 fps. If you wanted optimal performance, you might do asynchronous retrieval, combining that with [table view prefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) or [collection view prefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching).

Re complex expressions and text formatting, that's unlikely to ever introduce enough of a delay to prevent 60 fps. But don't guess (re this or images). You should analyze fps of "release" build (with optimizations turned on) through Instruments and see which, if either, of these have observable effect on fps. And test on your target physical devices, not the simulator, because it would be a shame to waste time prematurely optimizing a problem that doesn't occur on physical devices.

Comment: Would simple UIView animations in the cells also slow down the frame rate?

Comment: I'd suggest you stop guessing what might conceivably affect fps and empirically validate (with optimized, release builds) what actually does. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." Make sure you're in that 3% before you lose too much sleep about this. But in answer to your question, no, simple animations may well not affect fps adversely, though complex ones (e.g. animating complex view heirarchies with Gaussian blurs/shadows may well).

Answer (score 0):

Create image on background, set on UI thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let image = UIImage(named: "image")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

That's simplified example, you need to take care about scrolling and cell reusage.

Comment: I thought all things that change the UI need to happen on the Main Thread?

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion that's not a UI, you shouldn't change UI tree view on background threads, but you can load anything you want there

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Also, why do you put everything inside that block? That is, what is the difference between `.global(qos: .background).async` and `.main.async`?

Comment: Sorry if this question seems silly, but: So `global(qos: .background).async` runs on a background thread but `main.async` runs on the main thread, and the main thread is not the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, so retrieve the image in background thread, and then update imageview on the main thread (which is the thread for all UI updates). FYI, I would use `.background` if for prefetching. But if you're fetching for just-in-time presentation in the UI, you'd probably use `.userInitiated` or `.userInteractive`.